# implicit type casting should not works from char to String. How is this possible ?

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion

Converting from char to String should cause the following error: 
This code:

```
char [] arr = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
        String c = arr[1];
```

> Error :Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String

This code :

```
char [] arr = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
String c = "";
for(char i : arr) {
    c += i;
}
```

> Works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `+=` operator, like the `+` operator, will perform [*string conversion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11), when one of its operands is a `String` and the other isn't.

The code with `+=` will use string conversion to convert `i` from a `char` to a `String` for concatenation to `c`, a `String`.

The code with `=` will not use string conversion, because it's not in the list of acceptable conversions for assignment contexts, according to the [JLS, Section 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

Answer (score 4):

Since `String` is immutable, the compiler actually converts `+=` to

```
c = c + i;
```

which compiles to

```
c = new StringBuilder().append(c).append(i).toString();
```

and [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#method_summary) has `append` overloads for all the primitive types.